# Create a Tab bar in part of a navigation-based app

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uitabbarcontroller

I've yet to find an example that does this. A client wants a navigation-based app where two sections (one nav-screen each) need to have a few views, controlled by a tab bar. I'm having difficulty setting up the logic of connecting all of the elements and making sure the flow makes sense (ex. hitting the nav-bar's back button on any of the tabbed views will lead back to the same screen).

Comment: are you trying to do something like the AT&T app? Not sure if I can understand ur question

Comment: I wouldn't know what the AT&T app does. Basically I've got a navigation controller as my rootcontroller and need a way to instantiate and control a tab bar (or two) somewhere deep in the navigation tree, on one nav screen.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similiar question not long ago (if I understand your question right). This will add a tabbar as a rootcontroller and each tab has its own navigationcontroller.

[Right design pattern for tabbed navigation views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600956/right-design-pattern-for-tabbed-navigation-views/6601056#6601056)

EDIT

---

From [UITabBarController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Because the UITabBarController class inherits from the
>   UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have their own view that
>   is accessible through the view property. When deploying a tab bar
>   interface, you must install this view as the root of your window.
>   Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be
>   installed as a child of another view controller.

Comment: That's helpful, but not quite what I was looking for. To clear it up, I've got a navigation controller as my rootcontroller and need a way to instantiate and control a tab bar (or two) somewhere deep in the navigation tree, on one nav screen.

Comment: @John: Ah, okey I will update the answer and you will see why you should not do that, if you need such behavior you should use the toolbar, but I know that is not the same. I tried to use UITabBarController in deep down a nested hierarchy, but you will get warnings about rotation and the automatic relationships between the viewcontrollers will not work properly either. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jolly good has mentioned, Apple HIG suggests not to do such implementations.

The only other way I can suggest is to try implementing a custom view controller that looks/behaves like a tabbarcontroller and make use of that.

Another hack I can think of, not sure if it'll work or if its possible, create a tabbarcontrller the usual way and then set the hideBottomBar property, and make the bottom bar visible only when you want it to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, despite the documentation that @Jolly good cited.

As a real world example, let me describe a game of mine.  It consists of a UITabBarController (UITBC) and UINavigationController (UINC). The "main" window of the game is the Root view of the UINC, and when the game is active, it hides both the tab bar and nav bar to maximize screen real estate (not as necessary for iPad, but still...).

When the game is idle (paused, between rounds, etc.), it pushes the UITBC onto the nav bar.  It also tells the UITBC to make a particular VC selected.  That allows access to the additional screens (About, Scores, Instructions, Settings, etc.), and the player can navigate using the tab bar.  In addition to the additional views on the tab bar is the game controller that simply pops the UITBC from the nav bar to revert to the game view to un-pause, go to next round, etc.  (Obviously, the UITBC is cached within the game VC so it can be pushed back when necessary.)

Using this sort of logic, it is possible to mix and match tab bar and nav bar controllers for complex navigation. You can get away with this for games; just make sure that any non-game app follows Apple's HIG so as not to confuse the user.

I hope this helps.