# how to structure my objects when using uinavconttroller and uitabbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to understand what is a proper structure of the objects when using uinavigationcontroller with a tab bar.

I want my app to have the following structure: welcome/login screen -> 3 bar tabs.

I have the following objects/classes:

- AppDelegate
- WelcomeViewController
- TabController
- FirstTab
- SecondTab
- ThirdTab

I have also created a uinavcontroller under WelcomeViewController once the user clicks on "enter" to the app:

```
-(IBAction)aMethod:(id)sender {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
FirstView *controller = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
 navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES]; 
}
```

My question is - how should I manage the tab bar - where should I declare each one of its pieces, and will I need to create a uitabbarcontroller in this case (in which case, where?)).

I am very confused as to how to place the different tab bar related declarations and none of the examples/ tutorials our there were able to clarify this for me.

BTW - I started this app from a view based application.

Thanks!

Comment: I wrote this a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600956/right-design-pattern-for-tabbed-navigation-views/6601056#6601056

Comment: Thanks, Jolly, but that doesnt really answer my case, cause I dont even understand where to place my code...this is what I did per my list above: WelcomeViewController - just show an "enter" button to get into the app, then in TabController i declare the tabbarcontroller...is this the right way? Thanks!

Comment: The code i posted should be in the app delegate.

Comment: Can I still do this in the app delegate if I have a view controller in between? the app doesnt launch on the tab bar, there is a welcome screen before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set this up in code or you can do it using interface builder.

I prefer the interface builder method as you can visually see the structure of your view controllers.

This is how I do it...

1. In your `AppDelegate.h` add a property

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
   ```
2. In your `AppDelegate.m` firstly synthesize the property

   ```
   @synthesize tabBarController  = _tabBarController;
   ```
3. Set up the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method to look something like this (you may do more work in this method)

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
   {    

       [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

       return YES;
   }
   ```
4. In `MainWindow.xib` drag a `Tab Bar Controller` object onto your objects area (this is where your `AppDelegate` and `Window` objects are). 
   [image]
5. Ctrl + Drag from the `AppDelegate` to the `Tab Bar Controller` object and select the property that we just made.
   [image]

NOTE: Now we have a `Tab Bar Controller` set up and ready to roll.

6. There should be two tabs set up as an example. If you just want to use sub classes of `UIViewController` then just change the classes of these objects to represent your `UIViewController` sub classes.

[image]

7. If you want to use `UINavigationController` then drag a `UINavigationController` object onto your `Tab Bar Controller` object.

[image]

8. Now click the disclosure triangle on `UINavigationController` and change the class of its `ViewController` to be your custom subclass of `UIViewController`.
   [image]

Comment: +1 WOW thanks this is awesome! I was hoping for a solution that will prevent me from modifying the appDelegate since I have another screen between the app launch and the tab bar, but I am sure this will work out perfectly. Thanks!!!